# How to send key, value messages with flume to a kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

In console you add producer properties `--property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"` to produce key-value data into Kafka, but how to do this with flume? I tried to add

```
a1.sinks.k1.producer.parse.key=true 
a1.sinks.k1.producer.key.separator=:
```

in .conf file but was of no avail, the kafka treated the key like a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are console-producer CLI arguments, not ProducerConfig properties for Kafka (which are passed to Flume)

The key will always be a string, but you pass it via the headers of the Flume record

https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-sinks/flume-ng-kafka-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/kafka/KafkaSink.java#L193

Comment: That would make it work, thanks. For anyone else sees this, the way to do it is to add a header for the event in the interceptor, put a hashMap like "key", "key_something_something" in the header.